# Как узнать причину завершения работы MS ACCESS?

Tags: ms-access, обработка-ошибок

Иногда приложение MS ACCESS вылетает после нескольких минут работы, иногда вылетает на этапе загрузки стартовой формы. Как узнать что именно служит поводом для аварийного завершения работы приложения?

Comment: Приложение не должно просто вылетать, если не было явной комады Quit. Обязательно должна быть индикация ошибки. Описанное поведение говорит, скорее всего, о поврежденной установке Акцесса или проблемы в операционной системе. Все приложения вылетают? Если да, то переставьте офис для начала.

Comment: Нет, не все приложения вылетают. Вылеты замечены на 2ух базах: одна база, с формой просмотра, вылетает при запуску, вторая- вылетает через некоторое время после обновления подчиненной формы.

Comment: Бубен тогда в руки побольше и искать :) Попробуйте эти же приложения на других компьютерах, если удается воспроизвести, начните удалять код и контролы, пока не перестанет вылетать, тогда можно будет сузить круг поиска.. Да, в первую очередь  просто скопируйте все объекты в новую базу, так будете уверены, что база не битая.

Comment: `Forms.frmMain.Subfrm.form.recordsource = ""` крашит приложение. Но почему иногда с задержкой в несколько сек?